# Flask Rest-Api App running fine in localhost but not with public ip

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, portforwarding

Have my proper greetings at the very beginning.

I have recently built a simple rest-api app using python flask and flask_restful that takes an image as an input through POST request(using "curl" command), applies ocr on the image, saves the output of the ocr operation in a text file and then sends back that text file as the response (of the POST request).

The app works quite well in localhost.

I then set my ipv4 address manually to a particular ip address on my ubuntu pc. After that i forwarded the port my app is listening to(port: 5000) in my company's mikrotik router corresponding to my ip address. But the app does not work when the same POST request is made with the public ip address.By the way, the public ip is a real-ip.

I then changed my "***app.run(port = 5000, debug = True)***" statement to '***app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000, debug = True)***'. Still the app does not work for the POST request made with the public ip address

How to solve the problem? Please feel free to ask me any question if further information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "*app does not work*" exactly mean? Do you get an error response from your app? Or is your app not reachable at all? What error does your curl command show?

Comment: ubuntu should use its local IP (not public IP), flask should use needs `0.0.0.0` (not public IP) and rest should do port forwaring in routers - but if there are more routers (between flask and users on internet) then every router need port forwarding

Comment: sometimes it is simpler to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/product) but this generate random address everytime when you restart ngrok

Comment: Mr. @GinoMempin, i have answered your query. Please have a look.

Comment: Mr. @furas , i have already stated that i have provided "0.0.0.0" as the host in the app.run() statement. I tried my app with ngrok generated temporary public ip and my app works fine. But ngrok connection closes automatically after 2 hours. But i need permanent solution to this so that my app works even if public ip address is provided in the "curl -X POST" command.

Comment: I see you use `0.0.0.0` but you also mentioned that you use `public IP` but `0.0.0.0` is NOT public IP - and this why I add it. Between internet and your server there can be many router - your local router and Internet Provider router(s) - and you would have to set port forwarding on all routers - but usually you can't access Internet Provider router(s) to change it. But sometimes Internet Provider router(s) may have already port forwarding for standard ports like 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), eventually 21 (FTP), 22 (SSH), etc. and maybe you should use these ports.

Comment: I'm not sure but using on Linux `traceroute 8.8.8.8` you can see IPs of all routers between your computer and `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS) - and then you can see if there are other routers which can make problem.

Comment: BTW: when I use `27.147.184.162` in browser then I see login page for your `microtik` - and some urls - for example `http://27.147.184.162/graphs` gives me access to graphs of your ether cards. Better you should set access only from local network

Comment: BTW: using `nmap 27.147.184.162` I see all open port and 5000 is not open. So something wrong with your `port forwarding`. Doc  [nmap](https://nmap.org/download)